# Flex-box sticky footer with inner flex-box container with y axis scrolling

Tags: css

I know the subject is a mouthful but I couldn't find a better way to describe it in short.

I have a header, content-body, footer layout where the footer is 'sticky' using flex css, which works wonderfully. I have another container within the content-body that needs to expand to fill the available height and when it's contents are appended, it scrolls. So far, the only way I can get this to work is by setting the height of the content-body to a static px value, which breaks my desired vertical responsiveness.

Codepen of my attempt: http://codepen.io/sinrise/pen/QwKPKp

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;  /* to avoid scrollbars */
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;  /* use the flex model */
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;  /* learn more: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/ */
}
#header {
  background: yellow;
  height: 30px;  /* can be variable as well */
}
#body {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
}
.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fbfbfb;
}
#footer{
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Title</div>
  <div id="body">
    Body
    <div class="content">
      Content
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="item">Item 6</div>
      <div class="item">Item 7</div>
      <div class="item">Item 8</div>
      <div class="item">Item 9</div>
      <div class="item">Item 10</div>
      <div class="item">Item 11</div>
      <div class="item">Item 12</div>
      <div class="item">Item 13</div>
      <div class="item">Item 14</div>
      <div class="item">Item 15</div>
      <div class="item">Item 16</div>
      <div class="item">Item 17</div>
      <div class="item">Item 18</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer<br/>
    of<br/>
    variable<br/>
    height<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding

```css
#body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
    height: 0;    /* Reduce the height as much as possible... */
    flex-grow: 1; /* ...but make it fill all remaining space  */
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#header {
  background: yellow;
  height: 30px;
}
#body {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fbfbfb;
}
#footer {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Title</div>
  <div id="body">
    Body
    <div class="content">
      Content
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="item">Item 6</div>
      <div class="item">Item 7</div>
      <div class="item">Item 8</div>
      <div class="item">Item 9</div>
      <div class="item">Item 10</div>
      <div class="item">Item 11</div>
      <div class="item">Item 12</div>
      <div class="item">Item 13</div>
      <div class="item">Item 14</div>
      <div class="item">Item 15</div>
      <div class="item">Item 16</div>
      <div class="item">Item 17</div>
      <div class="item">Item 18</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer
    <br/>of
    <br/>variable
    <br/>height
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked so well! Thank you so much! I'm so in love with the flex-box thing! It's so clean, at least compared to how I was doing things before.

Comment: Good answer, works beautifully. A brief explanation of what reducing the content height to 0 does and why it makes it work would make it a great answer :)

Comment: @drewmoore `height: 0` or `flex-basis: 0` set the initial height to 0, and then it grows. Without that, the initial height would be given by the contents.

Comment: Yep, I figured that out but thought the explanation would improve the quality of the (again, already good) answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Forked your pen](http://codepen.io/azaslavsky/pen/gbwyxP) and got it to work.

What I changed:

- set minimum heights and "flex-basis" on `#header` and `#footer`
- changed "flex" to "flex-grow" on `#body`
- and, most importantly, instead of a `min-height` on the `#wrapper`, it's just a regular old `height: 100%;`